# ¿Como mantengo el valor de un campo select en Angular 8 al alternar entre diferentes vistas?

Tags: html, angular, spring, html-select

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Angular 8 (escasa experiencia con frameworks frontend) y tengo un campo select en una vista HTML que obtiene sus valores desde una consulta realizada mediante una API Rest al backend (spring).

Dicho campo select dispara un evento cuando se selecciona un valor del select, este evento se suscribe a un broker de mensajería y recibe los mensajes de cierto topic (según la selección) para mostrar los valores recibidos en tiempo real en unas casillas que van debajo del campo select.

Mi problema es: necesito poder cambiar de vista HTML a otra vista HTML de otro componente usando Angular Router (dentro de la misma instancia de la aplicación) y que al volver a la vista o componente inicial, el campo select siga con el valor que le habíamos seleccionado, es decir, como si en ningún momento nos hubiésemos ido a cargar otra vista HTML de otro componente. Espero haber expuesto bien mi problema.

No se si existe la posibilidad de guardar el valor de este select en alguna variable en memoria o algo así y que se pueda recuperar al volver a cargar el componente o algo parecido.

**Vista HTML:**

```
<select id="seleccionValor">
   <option>Elige valor...</option>
   <option *ngFor="let item of lista" [ngValue]="item">{{item.nombre}}</option>
</select>
```

**Componente Angular:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-smallmonitor',
  templateUrl: './smallmonitor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./smallmonitor.component.css']
})
export class SmallmonitorComponent implements OnInit {

  lista: item[];

  constructor(private itemService: ItemService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.itemService.getAllItems().subscribe(
      items => this.lista = items
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: No conozco Angular, pero se me ocurre que puedas colocar un input del tipo hidden capturas con jquery o javascript ese valor lo asignas al input, y validas que ese input te force el select a permanecer ahí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la forma de poder guardar el estado de alguna variable al cambiar de pagina es utilizando el sessionStorage (el guardado es temporal hasta que se cierre el navegador), o el localStorage (es permanente hasta que se borre).

De esta manera guardas algo.

> sessionStorage.setItem("nombre-de-variable" , variable)

```
let nombre: string = "Andrew";
sessionStorage.setItem("Nombre" , nombre);
```

Si vas a guardar algun JSON primero debes hacerle un stringify. ya que solo acepta string

> sessionStorage.setItem("nombre-de-variable" , JSON.stringify(variable))

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta panera obtienes algun valor:

> sessionStorage.getItem("nombre-de-variable")

```
sessionStorage.getItem("Nombre");
```

y si vas a obtener un JSON entonces le haces un parse.

> JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("nombre-de-variable"))

```
JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("nombre-de-variable"))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Utilizaré ésto junto a la utilización del sessionStorage para almacenar las credenciales del usuario que hace login en la aplicación.